# How do I install ruby gems, such as Sass, on Windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows, ssl-certificate

I did a search on this question and it seems that it is answered in detail for OSes other than  Windows.  I have Windows 7.  I seem to recall some mention of this but I didn't follow or see how I could fix the issue.
So I enter: gem install sass
and I did try running the command prompt as administrator.
So the error continues with Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0), here is why:
    Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect_returned=1 errono=0 state=SSLv3
    read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Can anyone direct me to a solution?  I did try rubygems.org.  It seems like there is more info for Unix based OSes, than there is for Windows.
Thanks so much in advance,
Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in this [bug report](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/704), your Ruby is not aware of the certificate authority that signed the rubygems.org certificate and thus can't verify that you are connecting to the right server.

You need to obtain a `.pem` file for the certificate authority and place it in the `site_ruby\2.0.0\rubygems\ssl_certs` directory of your Ruby installation.

I see quite a few people having success using the Mozilla CA bundle you can get from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html.